# Can IDEA connect to a CVS repo over extssh?

Tags: java, cvs, intellij-idea

Looks like IDEA is not supporting the extssh protocol for connecting to CVS by default. Is there a workaround available for accessing CVS through extssh?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why have you chosen to add the java tag?

Comment: Because this question is about IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: @Ninja: still don't think it is relevant

Comment: @Yaneeve: It is. Besides, let's pretend a .NET developer has ignored the `java` tag. If I hadn't added the `java` tag to this question, he would still see this question which is irrelevant to him. However, IDEA is a Java IDE, and it turns out extssh is also an Eclipse feature, so tagging this as Java makes sense as Java developers are very likely to be able to answer it. As you can see `matt b`, a Java developer I assume considering his contributions, was able to answer this question. End of story! ;)

Comment: technically IDEA can be used as an IDE for lots of other languages as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`extssh` is a protocol that is [internal to Eclipse only](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/task-team-cmdlineclient.htm):

> The extssh connection method is unique to Eclipse CVS and doesn't exist in the command-line CVS client.

Within IDEA, just select the `ssh (internal implementation)` connection method. It is the same thing.